# Drawing two same function, but looks different

Tags: octave

I have a problem with my project for studies.
Here are the formulas
[image], which I have to implement in Octave.
First is called FCzase, second FSzereg. Both should give same output, but as you can see here
[image]
on plots, they are different. Something is wrong with FSzereg. Can someone, please, help me find my mistake?

```
U = 1;    #voltage
T = 0.1;    #period
f = 1/T;  #frequency
n = 30;   #number of samples
m = 30;  #number of components in Fourier function
F1 = 0;
F2 = 0;

t= -T/2: T/n :T/2 - T/n + 2*T;
w = 2*pi*f;

for i = 1 : n
  if t(i) < 0
    FCzasu(i) = -4*U*t(i)^2/T^2;
  else
    FCzasu(i) = 4*U*t(i)^2/T^2;
  endif
endfor

FCzasu = [FCzasu FCzasu FCzasu];

for i = 2 : m
  F1 = F1 + (-1)^(i-1) * sin(i*w*t)/i;
endfor
for i = 1 : 2*m : 2
  F2 = F2 + sin(i*w*t)/i^3;
endfor

FSzereg = (2*U/pi)*(sin(w*t) + F1) - (8*U/(pi^3))*F2;

FFTSzereg = abs(fft(FSzereg));
FFTCzasu = abs(fft(FCzasu));

k=0 : 1 : 3*n-1 ;
fre = k * f/3;

subplot(2,2,1)
plot(t, FCzasu)
xlabel('Czas [s]'); 
ylabel('Napiecie [V]')

subplot(2,2,2)
stem(fre, FFTCzasu,'.')
title('{\bf Widmo}');
grid on;
xlabel('Czestotliwosc [Hz]'); 
ylabel('Amplituda [V]')

subplot(2,2,3)
plot(t, FSzereg)
xlabel('Czas [s]'); 
ylabel('Napiecie [V]')

subplot(2,2,4)
stem(fre, FFTSzereg,'.')
title('{\bf Widmo}');
grid on;
xlabel('Czestotliwosc [Hz]'); 
ylabel('Amplituda [V]')
```

Comment: You have beautiful graphics there but from programming point of view, nothing is wrong with `FSzereg`, it outputs something you've coded it to do. It is difficult for anyone without familiarity with the problem to understand why those two cycles should populate arrays with same values. You probably should consult teacher on that matter.

Comment: As a guess, I'd assume that you are trying to replicate a discontinuous signal `FCzasu` using sines and cosines in `FSzereg`. That approach will always yield some degree of errors. Try increasing the number of hamonics `m`.

Comment: You were right, I consulted teacher and he said that everything is alright and this kind of 'problems' are normal. Thank you :)